# Change selection on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have function in that i have on table my problem is i want selection like on press down arrow select 1st row and so on please help mi(My Table inside Bootstrap Modal)

this is my code.

```js
if(keycode == '40'){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));       
 }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr id="row1">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What??? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to navigate between dynamically populated li elements using up or down keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631581/how-to-navigate-between-dynamically-populated-li-elements-using-up-or-down-keys)

Comment: What is the problem you're facing with this code? What is the question?

Comment: if i press down arrow i want focus on 2nd row in i again press down arrow then it go to 3rd row an so on

Answer (score 0):

If you want on key press to do or call something then this is something for you

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode

  if(key == '40'){
   alert("hi");          
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get started!

**P.S:** Before navigating with arraow keys, click the result window to activate

```js
$(function() {
  $('table tr:eq(1)').addClass('selected');

  $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($('table tr.selected').index() != 1) {
        $('table tr.selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected');
      }
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($('table tr.selected').index() != $('table tr:last-child').index()) {
        $('table tr.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr id="row1">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```